# UIView animation on completion not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, animatewithduration

I have a problem using a slider to trigger a series of animations, here's the code:

```
-(void)slideAlpha:(id)sender{

  self.bigPhotoViewA.alpha = self.alphaSlider.value;

  if (self.alphaSlider.value == 1){

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                     animations:^{
                         self.alphaSlider.alpha = 0;
                     } completion:nil
    ];

    [self performSelector:@selector(nextPhotoAnimation) withObject:self afterDelay:5.0 ];
  }
}

-(void) nextPhotoAnimation{

  self.alphaSlider.value = 0;

  [UIView animateWithDuration:2
                   animations:^{
                       self.bigPhotoViewA.alpha = 0.0;
                       self.bigPhotoView.alpha = 0.0;
                       self.smallPhotoView.center = CGPointMake(startX, startY);
                   }
                   completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                       NSLog(@"Animation ended");
                       self.smallPhotoView.image = ((UIImage *)[smallImagesArray objectAtIndex:imageCount]);
                   }
  ];
}
```

So, when the slider reaches a value of 1, `nextPhotoAnimation` is launched after a delay. So far so good. The problem comes inside `nextPhotoAnimation`. The `animations` block runs ok, but the `completion` block runs several times every time `nextPhotoAnimation` is called. I get the `NSLog` from 6 to 9 times displayed when `nextPhotoAnimation` starts, and then I get it again at the right time, after 2 seconds.

[image: NSLog]

I've tried to replicate the problem with simpler code and the `animation`/`completion` flow works just fine.

Comment: check `BOOL finished` in `completion:^(BOOL finished)
`

Comment: @Akhilrajtr, I've tried putting the whole `completion` block inside an  `if(finished){...}` statement. Still doesn't work properly. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in `nextPhotoAnimation`,

```
-(void) nextPhotoAnimation{

    self.alphaSlider.value = 0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2
               animations:^{
                   self.bigPhotoViewA.alpha = 0.0;
                   self.bigPhotoView.alpha = 0.0;
                   self.smallPhotoView.center = CGPointMake(startX, startY);
               }
               completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                   if (finished) {
                       NSLog(@"Animation ended");
                       self.smallPhotoView.image = ((UIImage *)[smallImagesArray objectAtIndex:imageCount]);
                   }
               }
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

neither you are using

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

nor

[UIView commitAnimations];

Best way is to create a UIView and then use the protocols.call your methods using [self YOURMETHOD]; in the View.
:-)

Comment: As it says in the `UIView` class reference about `beginAnimations` and `commitAnimations`:

 "Use of the methods in this section is discouraged in iOS 4 and later. Use the block-based animation methods instead."

I'd prefer a block-based animation solution for this issue.